# DataGridView : Mouse scroll and down arrow button hold behave different for large number of rows

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagrid, datagridview, grid

In Slow Pc having Pentium processor, for DataGridView having some about 500 rows and more looks like dragging the same row, while

1. Scrolling the grid by mouse scroll bar.
2. If down arrow mark is pressed and it is hold. But this is not seen while dragging the rows with the mouse pointer.

Here is sample code.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 0 To 10
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i, "Column" & i)
        Next
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        For i = 1 To 500
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        Next
        For i = 1 To 500
            For j = 0 To 2
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = (1000 + i) & "_" & j & "A"
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please, post some code or provide any kind of proof of a proper understanding of the situation. BTW., I have taken a quick look at your profile and you ask a lot; get quite a few answers but usually don't accept any as the valid one. Are you so demanding that nothing fits within your expectations? Or your questions are so difficult and the answerers so bad that you don't consider that they deserve your approval?

Comment: @varocarbas Till now which ever answer has helped me for those i have marked it as answered.I have asked 90 question out of which i have marked 16 as accepted answers.In dba.stackexchange.com i have marked 10 as answered out of 30

Comment: I see... what means that the answers given to your last 15 questions haven't been useful for you. That is, you are really demanding or your questions are way too complicated; so, I guess that I will not even try to answer this one :)